# Polygon is not draggable

Tags: typescript, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I drawn a polygon using `MapboxGL.ShapeSource` and added `MapboxGLView.PointAnnotation` on every point to make points draggable.

But i'm facing issues

When i finished the draw of Polygon, i'm not able to move or drag the polygon

```
 Polygon Data => {"coordinates": [[73.66673886505973, 21.78762724903116], [73.66889536107317, 21.791363112441147], [73.66555869310983, 21.79017760900554]]}
```

here my code

```
 <MapboxGL.Animated.ShapeSource
     id={'Polygon'}
     maxZoomLevel={17}
    onPress={(event: any) => {
      console.log('Shape is pressed ', event);
    }}
    shape={{
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: coordinates,
      },
    }}>

    <MapboxGL.FillLayer
      id="routefill"
      sourceID="Polygon"
      style={{fillColor: fillColor}}
    />
    <MapboxGL.LineLayer
      id="routeline"
      sourceID="Polygon"
      belowLayerID="routefill"
      style={{
        lineWidth: 5,
        // lineOpacity: 0.5,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineDasharray: [2, 2],
        lineColor: strokeColor,
      }}
    />

   </MapboxGL.Animated.ShapeSource>
```

can anyone please help me how can i make polygon draggable